# Kloxo/CentOS 5.7 install .p12 certificate

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate

I have just got a free StartSSL certificate, I received a .p12 file, and only a .key file. I'm not really sure how to install this on my server and replace the current one. It's running Kloxo latest and it's not accepting any of the files.

Is there any way I can convert this to the traditional .key/.cert file and/or install this another way?

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Certificate**

1. Login into your startssl account
2. click at Tool Box -> Retrieve Certificate.

Here you can get .crt format for your certificate.

select your hostname and click continue to get your certificate.

**Key:**

you given key during Certificates wizard and please keep in safe place. key will not given after certificate was issued.

Decrypt the private key with the OpenSSL utility: `openssl rsa -in ssl.key -out ssl.key` or use the utility from the Tool Box.

**Install into kloxo**

1. go to home, click SSL certificates. click upload txt files
2. copy & paste Key, Crt and StartSSL CA and click Add
3. click ssl certificates again and select previously created certificate
4. click Set SSL for kloxo and select your slave ID or master ID

Answer (score 0):

A .p12 file is a [PKCS#12 Personal Information Exchange Syntax Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS12) file.  I think the info on [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/405545/1174411) will help you convert the .p12 into PEM format (e.g. something that can work as a .cert/.cer file).  In particular, there's even a link to a site where you can do the conversion online:  https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-converter.html

Once you have the .cer file, I think Kloxo will be happy to import it.